# How to import protobuff message in different package's .proto file correctly?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have two packages like this

```
com.abc.
         protobuf.
                    share.proto
         depart.
                    detect.proto
```

and the conent of  share.proto like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.adc.protobuf;
message Test{}
```

and the content of detect.proto like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.adc.depart;
import "com/abc/protobuf/share.proto"
```

and compile share.proto in it's dir like this:

```
protoc -I=. --python_out=. share.proto
```

then compile detect.proto in it's dir like this:

```
protoc -I=/pathToSrcDir/ -I=. --python_out=. detect.proto
```

and

```
pathToSrcDir has been added to PYTHONPATH
```

all compilations work fine,but when run a python script which

```
from com.abc.depart import detect_pb2
```

got this error

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "detect.proto":
  detect.proto: Import "com/abc/protobuf/share.proto" has not been loaded.
  com.abc.depert.XClass.ymethod: "com.abc.protobuf.Test" seems to be defined in "share.proto", which is not imported by "detect.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

How to solve this import problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Some guy answered my question](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/4176) and in short, an inconsistent use of includes is the root of the problem.

The solution is

```
cd /pathToSrcDir/
protoc -I. --python_out=. com/abc/protobuf/share.proto 
protoc -I. --python_out=. com/abc/depart/detect.proto
```

Comment: This worked for me as well - note that I ran the command from python, which has the grpc plugin installed, fyi:

```python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --proto_path=com/mycompany/stuff/v1/ --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. com/mycompany/stuff/v1/groups_info.proto com/mycompany/stuff/v1/class_info.proto com/mycompany/stuff/v1/user_info.proto```

Comment: This is insane! Your short answer just solve all of my confusions, after change all include options (and also generate output directory names) and protobuf import instructions. All things works perfectly!!! This just saves me hours of time of searching google.
Yet, there still another problem with python binding, the generated python script cannot handle relative imports correctly, but this can be fixed by running a post process to fix the import instruction. Thanks for this answer so much.